# Need to do sed to replace ${D} string in do_install()

Tags: sed, yocto, openembedded

I am doing a yocto recipe:

```
do_install () {
  install -d -m 755 ${D}/opt/intel
  sed -i 's/\/opt\/intel/\/TEST_PATH/' silent.cfg
}
```

This will work, but I want to replace TEST_PATH to ${D} in the recipe, the follows will bitbake fail:

```
do_install () {
  install -d -m 755 ${D}/opt/intel
  sed -i 's/\/opt\/intel/${D}/' silent.cfg
}
```

error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: Is `${D}` a shell variable?  IOW, given the code  `D=arf; sed 's/foo/${D}/' <<< foo`, would the output you expect be **1)**  *"arf"*, or **2)** a literal *"${D}"*?   Running it will show that **2)** is the output, but perhaps **1)** was the OP's intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know about the yocto aspect, which I am assuming replaces `${D}` for you, but in sed the substitute command can use any delimiter, not just `/`.  For example, if your variable `${D}` doesn't contain a colon `:` you could use that:

```
sed -i 's:/opt/intel:${D}:' silent.cfg
```